# How to get all time high and low price of bitcoin and other altcoins

Tags: api, altcoin, trading

I am fetching current price of 500 coins from coinmarketcap.com using their api for some crypto research. I also the all time high and low of these coins to see how much has the value appreciated/ depreciated since all time high / low.

Does any one know where I can find the all time high and low of the coins. 
Could't find any api/website offering the same. Its okey even if its a website because, I just want fetch the data once. I can update my record if the coin hits a new high / low after that using live data from coinmarketcap.

Comment: https://chasing-coins.com/api supports ath

Answer (score -1):

There is a special preset for ATH on [coinpaprika.com](https://coinpaprika.com/?tab=ath)